# Javascript to Python - low/high byte addition

Tags: javascript, python

I try to convert the following JS code into Python code.
It's not my function, but I have to use it.

```
function combineBytes(high, low) {
  high = parseInt(high || "0", 10);
  low = parseInt(low || "0", 10);
  high * 4294967296 + low;
}
```

Does anyone know how to convert `high || "0"` into Python?

Comment: `high or "0"`?..

Comment: Instead of asking for code to be translated, it would be better to describe your actual requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function can be done in the following way.

```
def combineBytes(high, low):
  high = int(high or 0)
  low = int(low or 0)
  return high * 4294967296 + low

print(combineBytes(2, None))
```

By default the base to transform is 10.

In Python "or" is replaced by || in js

`high || "0"` is equivalent to `high or 0` in python.

keep in mind that the data type must be integer and `"0"` would be string

Return:

```
8589934592
```

Answer (score 0):

high is passed argument to the function  ,this will work

```
   int (high or 0);
```